# python global variable called inside method

Tags: python, global-variables

I have a few classes in a python file. In `classA` I have a method called `a1`

```
def a1(self):
    global p
    p = abc
```

outside of all classes is a method called `z` which just `returns p`

```
def z():
   return p
```

Inside of one the other class called `classB` is a method call `b1`

```
def b1(self):
    print(z())
```

When `classB` first runs and goes through the `init` and class set up it prints out the `z` function, however when it reloads the class and tries to print it again it gives an error saying `p` is not defined inside of the `z` function. How do I fix this?

Comment: please post a minimum viable reproducible example ...

Comment: Also please share the code you are using to run and print the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have left out some crucial details ...

```
p=None
def z():
   return p
class X:
   def a1(self):
     global p
     p = "abc"

print(z())
X().a1()
print(z())
```

Comment: ok so is there a way to set it so i dont have to call a1() after a1() has already ran?

Comment: a1 is only running once ... i have no idea what your asking could you elaborate? you don't need to call a1 at all if you dont want to...

Comment: ok I dont call the method but now it returns only None not abc

Comment: thats the value of p ... until you change it ... one way you could change it is to call the method ...